# How do I add a custom font to an Android Application?

Tags: java, android, textview, custom-font

How do I add a custom font into a `<TextView />` or a Custom view for an Android application?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
  Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
  "fonts/Erika Type.ttf");
  tx.setTypeface(custom_font);
```